# Using Excel N function with arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A fairly basic question, but I have been unable to find a previous answer - perhaps partly because it is difficult to search on 'N function' without getting a lot of false matches.

The N function is a concise way of returning a number if a cell contains a number or zero if it contains text. It is shorter than using the ISNUMBER function and potentially useful in array formulae.

Why can I write

```
=SUM(N({1,2,3}))
```

and get the answer 6, but if I write

```
=SUM(N(A1:A3))
```

and A1:A3 contains some numbers, I just get the first number?

If I go to Evaluate Formula, it shows that  it is not treating A1:A3 as an array, even if I enter it as an array formula.

Is there a way of coercing the N function to work in an array formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

`=SUM(N(+A1:A3))`

The unary plus operator is here sufficient to coerce an array return from the range being passed.

It is also convenient that the results of applying the unary operator to each of the values in the range are such that, when we then pass them to N, the resulting values will be equivalent to those we would have obtained had we simply applied the N function to each.

Regards

Comment: So simple! The -- operator seems to work as well, but I notice that =SUM(+A1:A3) gives a different answer to =SUM(--A1:A3) when applied to 1, TRUE, 3.

Comment: Yes, and of course: 1, "X", 3 will force =SUM(--A1:A3) to return an error, though =SUM(+A1:A3) will return 4. Re Boolean types =SUM(+A1:A3) is equivalent to =SUM(A1:A3), with A1:A3 containing 1, TRUE, 3. Recall that Boolean values passed to SUM as part of a worksheet range (or array) are not coerced to their numerical equivalents, though they are when passed as arguments, i.e. =SUM(1,TRUE,3).

Comment: Brilliant, I think I understand that better now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option appears to be - `{=N(SUM(A1:A3))}` (entered as an array)

Comment: This seems to work as you wish - if you place a non number string in the range, it still sums the remaining values

Comment: Thanks - I see what you mean that this would normally give the right answer, but strictly speaking it's not quite the same as using N because 1,TRUE,3 should give 5 rather than 4.

Comment: I now see more clearly what you were after, but I'm not having any luck either. If you use the function on a spare column =N(A1) then add the row above, this would eventually give you the sum of what you want at the last line. Its a shame there's no satisfying array part though, and I cant find any ways round it