# Googlesheets - ArrayFormula to calculate the weighted average of two rows ignoring text cells

Tags: javascript, excel

[Horribly clunky formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCSRE.png)

I'm trying to get a weighted average for the "Overall" column in my spreadsheet.  I've only attached a screenshot and not the sheet because it's a huge horrible mess, and this is a specific (and I feel probably simple) question I'm trying to figure out.

I've tried several iterations of ArrayFormula and ISNUMBER etc, but I've run out of ideas and am just guessing at this stage.  I'd have thought there would be some kind of combination of (F3:CL3)*(F4:CL4) that would ignore the text cells.

Please help me get rid of that abomination of a formula I have right now!  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(+J3:CL3)*N(+J4:CL4))
```

entered as a normal formula to get the sum of products, ignoring any text values.

Admittedly it is a mysterious piece of Excel - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006937/using-excel-n-function-with-arrays)

This is longer but less tricky:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(J3:CL3),J3:CL3)*IF(ISNUMBER(J4:CL4),J4:CL4))
```

must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Having said all that, this simple formula should also work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(J3:CL3,J4:CL4)
```

According to the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e):

```
SUMPRODUCT treats array entries that are not numeric as if they were zeros.
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, that works perfectly!  I used the first formula - haven't tested the others, but appreciate the comprehensive answer! <3

Comment: Glad that worked for you - so used to using SUMPRODUCT as an array formula substitute that I didn't think of the  more simple answer till later.

Comment: I've never used the N function so it was good to learn something new.  Mind you, most of my formula and function coding is googling, ripping formulas/code and hacking it up to do what I need it to do.  So when I'm not completely understanding the syntax it can get frustrating when something doesn't work!  :D