# Excel: How to take a weighted average where blank values cause proportional weighting shifts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, weighted-average

I have five categories. Each category has a weight in row 2 and a value in row 3. In cell `G3` I'd like to have a formula that takes the weighted average of all of the categories.

The major caveat, some categories will not have values. If a category has a blank value, its weighting should be evenly distributed to the remaining categories that do have values, and then the weighted average should be taken. See Below for two examples:

[image]

In this photo, cell `C3` is missing a value. There are 4 categories remaining that do have values. So its weighting of 0.2 will be redistributed four ways, so each of the remaining categories will have have (02./4 =0.05) increase in their weightings in the weighted average. The highlighted cell is the desired result.

I will further illustrate with one additional scenario:

[image]

In the above scenario there are two categories with missing values and both have a weighting of 0.15. There are 3 categories with values. So each missing category will redistribute 0.15/3 = 0.05 weighting to the three remaining categories. So each category will have an increased weighting of 2*0.05 = 0.1 because of the 2 missing categories. The yellow box displays the correct weighted average.

One further caveat, it would be great if the formula could be dynamic enough to work for ranges of larger than 5 categories. Any ideas on how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me - I have a feeling it could be simplified, but it just works through the steps outlined in the question:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F2*B3:F3)+SUMPRODUCT(SUMPRODUCT((B3:F3="")*B2:F2)*B3:F3)/COUNT(B3:F3)
```

[image]

If the blank cells are not actually blank but contain "" returned as the result of a formula, you could try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F2*N(+B3:F3))+
SUMPRODUCT(SUMPRODUCT((B3:F3="")*B2:F2)*N(+B3:F3))/COUNT(B3:F3)
```

as suggested by the brilliant @XOR LX in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006937/using-excel-n-function-with-arrays)

Comment: thank you for your reply! How would you edit this part of your equation ```(B3:F3="")``` if the empty cell is not actually a blank but an index function returning nothing?

Comment: Doesn't INDEX() return a zero if the referenced cell is blank? In that case 

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F2*B3:F3)+SUMPRODUCT(SUMPRODUCT((B3:F3=0)*B2:F2)*B3:F3)/COUNT(B3:F3)`

Would probably do it. (fair warning, I didn't test it).

Comment: I tried putting ="" in a cell instead of blank but it gave #Value! There is a workaround - I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this array formula does it. Enter it using **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**

```
=SUM(IF(B3:F3<>0,B3:F3*B2:F2))/SUM(IF(B3:F3<>0,B2:F2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but even when I enter it using ctrl shift enter, making it an array formula it returns ```#VALUE```

Comment: The formula only returns a number for me when there are no blanks. Otherwise it returns ```#VALUE```

Comment: Do you normally use `,` as separator or `;` ?

Comment: Or maybe your blank is not "", but rather a space " "

Comment: I've always used ```,```

Comment: I just realized that if I deleted the numbers out again it worked. You are right, its possible there was a space

Comment: thank you for your reply! How would you edit your equation if the empty cells are not actually a blank but an ```index``` function returning nothing?